# How to handle expired sessions in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm using Express and Passport.js in my project. I handle login and logout users. But, if the user does not logout, i don't handle expired session. I want to handle expired session or i want to access current session list in the server. Are there any methods for this?

Comment: are you using express' session storage to hold the sessions?

Comment: I researched it. Everyone said that use the Redis. But i don't want to use any database. Is there another way for this? Also, I don't know how to access session storage in express.

Comment: okay man.the thing is you can store your session and save your variables on mongo with express-session.if you dont know it i can share some links with you.

Comment: Do I have to use any database? Is it not possible using only memory?

Comment: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html 
check this link mate.if it works for you let me know so i can put it as answer

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I solved this problem by using different way.